# Parse Javascript Platform Change Password Error

Tags: parse-platform

I defined a cloud code：

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateUser", async (request) => {

    const query = new Parse.Query("User");
    query.get(request.params.id, {useMasterKey:true})
        .then(function(user) {
            user.set("username", request.params.username);
            user.set("password", request.params.password);
            user.set("gender", request.params.gender);
            return user.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
        });
});
```

Return has been changed successfully.
But, using the new password to log in on the mobile app, the password is incorrect.
`{"code":101, "stack": "Error": Invalide username/password}`

Comment: How do you plan to secure this function?  As it stands, anyone could change any users username and password?

Comment: Internal use, permissions do not matter.-_-

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the first promise. Also try to use `setUsername` and `setPassword`. It would be something like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateUser", async (request) => {

    const query = new Parse.Query("User");
    return query.get(request.params.id, {useMasterKey:true})
        .then(function(user) {
            user.setUsername(request.params.username);
            user.setPassword(request.params.password);
            user.set("gender", request.params.gender);
            return user.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
        });
});
```

Comment: This is the Javascript API:

Comment: ```setPassword(password, options) → {Boolean}```
```Calls set("password", password, options) and returns the result.```

Comment: https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.User.html#setPassword